# Android - read only file system IOException - not writing to root

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to use a MediaRecorder to record audio, and it's refusing to let me open the file. I am not writing to root directory as are all the other questions on here.

The code:

```
baseFilename = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/loopRecord"; //returns /data/user/0/com.example.myName.looperpedal/files/loopRecord
//and then later
r.setOutputFile(baseFilename + (++numLoops));
```

This causes `prepare()` to fail with:

```
9-20 07:55:49.919 14394-14394/com.example.brydon.looperpedal W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: null1: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)
09-20 07:55:49.920 14394-14394/com.example.brydon.looperpedal W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:455)
09-20 07:55:49.920 14394-14394/com.example.brydon.looperpedal W/System.err:     at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:247)
09-20 07:55:49.920 14394-14394/com.example.brydon.looperpedal W/System.err:     at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:128)
09-20 07:55:49.920 14394-14394/com.example.brydon.looperpedal W/System.err:     at android.media.MediaRecorder.prepare(MediaRecorder.java:1136)
09-20 07:55:49.920 14394-14394/com.example.brydon.looperpedal W/System.err:     at com.example.brydon.looperpedal.MainActivity.setUpRecorder(MainActivity.java:52)
09-20 07:55:49.920 14394-14394/com.example.brydon.looperpedal W/System.err:     at com.example.brydon.looperpedal.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:38)
09-20 07:55:49.921 14394-14394/com.example.brydon.looperpedal W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6912)
09-20 07:55:49.921 14394-14394/com.example.brydon.looperpedal W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
09-20 07:55:49.921 14394-14394/com.example.brydon.looperpedal W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2900)
09-20 07:55:49.921 14394-14394/com.example.brydon.looperpedal W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3008)
09-20 07:55:49.921 14394-14394/com.example.brydon.looperpedal W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
09-20 07:55:49.921 14394-14394/com.example.brydon.looperpedal W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650)
09-20 07:55:49.921 14394-14394/com.example.brydon.looperpedal W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-20 07:55:49.921 14394-14394/com.example.brydon.looperpedal W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
09-20 07:55:49.921 14394-14394/com.example.brydon.looperpedal W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6688)
09-20 07:55:49.922 14394-14394/com.example.brydon.looperpedal W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
09-20 07:55:49.922 14394-14394/com.example.brydon.looperpedal W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
09-20 07:55:49.922 14394-14394/com.example.brydon.looperpedal W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
09-20 07:55:49.922 14394-14394/com.example.brydon.looperpedal W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)
09-20 07:55:49.922 14394-14394/com.example.brydon.looperpedal W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
09-20 07:55:49.922 14394-14394/com.example.brydon.looperpedal W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:187)
09-20 07:55:49.923 14394-14394/com.example.brydon.looperpedal W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:441)
09-20 07:55:49.923 14394-14394/com.example.brydon.looperpedal W/System.err:     ... 17 more
```

In my manifest file, I do have:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Although I'm not using external storage, is there an internal storage permission?

All of the other questions seem solved using the solution I have, so I don't know what I'm missing.

Comment: You're using emulator or real device?

Comment: real device - check my answer, it was a simple mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have seen the the stack trace - the file it's trying to write to is called `null1`.

Turns out I was trying to create the mediarecorder before building the filename.

Answer (score 0):

getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() path only use your application or this data not share only your application visible this data.